# how to get -Xmx by ganalyzing java_opt?

Tags: jvm

eg：-Xms1g -Xmx1g -XX:SurvivorRatio=2 -XX:+UseCMSInitiatingOccupancyOnly -XX:CMSInitiatingOccupancyFraction=75

JVM did not start.
so my quesion is how to analyze java_opt using jdk method.

thanks.

Comment: fengshen, you should provide a more context or at least a clear definition as to what you want.

Comment: can you paste the jvm crash log?

Answer (score 0):

```
Runtime.getRuntime().maxMemory()
```